# Issue While redirecting from non www URL to www URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, cakephp-1.3

Hi On our website we are facing a issue like when we enter url without www for eg. `example.com/xyz` in this case after redirect it is converting to `www.example.com/?url=xyz` but it should be redirect to simply like: `www.example.com/xyz`

**So we are getting extra `?url= in URL`**

We have used code for redirect non www url to www in our htaccess file. Code for redirect in htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
```

We have also tried this code but not work:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your redirect rule *before* the routing rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @JOnLin for reply but its not solving my issue still problem are same ?url= in the URL is coming

Comment: I have checked after delete all cache even checked in two browsers. This problem only coming when I am trying to open any other page apart from home page like example.com/xyz if I try only for example.com it redirect fine www.example.com